# Data Insert tool keep saying "mkdir(): File exists in"

Tags: php, mysql

I have created this admin user page where data can be inserted. But everytime I try to execute it says:

```
mkdir(): File exists in rental/search/add_property_2.php on line 98
```

Here is the code:

```
$p_img9 = $_POST['p_img9'];
$p_img10 = $_POST['p_img10'];*/


if (!file_exists('tmp_imgs/'.$property_id)) {     // Creating Temprory Directroy for images
mkdir('tmp_imgs/tmp_'.$property_id, 0777, true);    ...Line 98
}

foreach ($_FILES['p_img']['name'] as $f => $name) {
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $name);
$extension = end($temp);
```

Seeking Help On This

Property Id is auto generated and on previous page to this its defined as

```
$property_id =  get_new_property_id();...
```

and second page where getting error

```
$property_id = $_POST['property_id'];..
```

Comment: what is `$property_id`. you should define this.

Comment: Thanks @Masum.. Property Id is auto generated and on previous page to this its defined as $property_id =  get_new_property_id();... and on this page $property_id = $_POST['property_id'];.. Am I doing some thing wrong?

Comment: for some reason your `get_new_property_id()` is returning same thing (string, int, float etc whatever), each time you are requesting. check it. and if so fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check condition doesn't match the directory you are creating. You can fix it like so

```
$directory = 'tmp_imgs/tmp_'.$property_id;
if (!file_exists($directory)) {
  mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
}
```